# Training RMSE higher than Validation RMSE in H2O

Tags: validation, deep-learning, regression, h2o

I am using the H2O-DeepLearning Model for a Regression Problem. What i observe is that Training RMSE is higher than Validation RMSE. I am using the model with default parameter which is two hidden layers with 200 Neurons each and no l1/l2 Regularization. Activation is Rectifier. No Dropout added.

I am wondering how can i tune the hyperparameters two get Training RMSE below Validation RMSE?

Any hints for parameter?

I am using separate Train, Validation and Test-Set. Training Data has 1958826 Samples, Validation and Test set have 599380 Samples each.

R-squared Value is around 0.65 - 0.7

Edit: While I am experiencing lower Validation RMSE than Training RMSE, it seems that the Values for Residual-Deviance in Training are lower than for Validation. So this seems fine.

Edit:
Training:
RMSE: 0.3592
Deviance: 0.0071

Validation:
RMSE: 0.3403
Deviance: 0.0082

I am doing quantile regression (if that is any help) and i have separate train/test data sets, while i splitted the test-set into validation and test with the h2o-split_frame-method.

Comment: can you post what you get for rmse and residual deviance for your train and valid sets? how did you split up your data (was it a random split?). Do you think your validation dataset is representative of your train set?

Comment: @Lauren i updated the post.

Comment: in the future please don't double post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/378660/training-rmse-higher-than-validation-rmse-in-h2o

Comment: @Lauren okay thanks. but did the added information help you? Do you have an answer?

Comment: sorry for the delayed response. It's hard to say why you are seeing these results, especially since the difference is small. I would take a look at the distribution of each of your features and if there is a noticeable difference between the feature distributions in the validation set compared to the train. Maybe there is something about the split that makes the valid set easier to predict. If you run multiple trials, with different seeds, do you ever see valid outperform train? here's some more info on tuning: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials/tree/master/tutorials/deeplearning

Comment: provide some solutions you can try, hopefully it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few recommendations of what you can try.

1. Train for more epochs
2. Decrease batch size
3. Increase the number of neurons in the hidden layers.

It is possible that a low number of epochs is the cause for worse train performance in your regression problem.